# SQL Server - Over partition with ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING not working?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> UNBOUNDED PRECEDING Applies to: SQL Server 2012 (11.x) through SQL
> Server 2017.
>
> Specifies that the window starts at the first row of the partition.
> UNBOUNDED PRECEDING can only be specified as window starting point.

How come then, when using this:

```
   avg(Qty) over (partition by [Name] 
    ORDER BY [Period] desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
```

I still get rolling averages.

I understand that above construction should get me equivalent of `Select TOP(3) avg(qty)...`, at least according to the documentation.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Post some sample data and expected results, please.  See [ask] and [mcve] for further details.

Comment: You expect it to give you the `TOP(3)` and yet you've explicitly said "give me as many rows as are available" (a.k.a `UNBOUNDED`)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - *Specifies that the window starts at the first row of the partition. UNBOUNDED PRECEDING can only be specified as window starting point.* Unless I'm parsing that in a very, very wrong way, the quote does not say what you say it says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After research, test and analysing the available documentation one thing to remember is that my understanding was incomplete: when working with `ROWS` in any configuration the reference point is always current row. So my query:

```
avg(Qty) over (partition by [Name] 
    ORDER BY [Period] desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
```

simply means "get all rows from start of the partition of the window to current row and 2 rows more". The unspoken part is "current row", which is there always regardless.

Thanks to [Damien_the_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) for stating the obvious, which kept me thinking.